# why does Wireshark on Mac OS X runs on X11?

Tags: macos, xorg, wireshark

I know little bit about X11 and i have used it for remotely interacting with my applications on my Linux machine. But I don't understand why running Wireshark locally will start an X11 process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wireshark UI is using Gtk, a common unix gui toolkit (gtk = GIMP Toolkit) which is targeted for X11. As long as there's not native (Cocoa-) build for OS X, X11 will always be required to run Wireshark on a Mac.